# Windows folder Pictures and Documents are not recognised by R or Python

Tags: python, r, windows, powershell, directory-structure

I am on Windows, and my session folders (Pictures, Documents and maybe others) are not recognized by R or Python in a weird way.

I can navigate there, read but not save anything. I looked at the authorization parameter and opened windows PowerShell as Administrator, nothing works. I have similar issue with R (Rstudio)

In this example I cannot create a file

[image]

Here I cannot duplicate a file that I can read

[image]

I am on a French computer, that I used to have with a mixed American setup. I don't know if that could have created the issue.

Thank you

I tried to save a picture in windows Pictures folder, without success. I had to save it in my User folder.

R has some weird bug which seems to be related to impossibility to access the Documents folder

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.